# Angular.js dependencies order for third party libraries

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-controller

First of all all third-party libraries  should be wrapped in angular module so it can be added as a dependency to other angular modules.

for example

```
angular.module('lodash', [])
      .factory('_', function($window) { return $window._;});
```

and inject it into other module like:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['lodash']);
```

The question is, where should third-party libraries be located in dependency list at start or at end?

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(function($scope, _){});
```

VS

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(function(_, $scope){});
```

Both cases works, but what is your opinion on that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It should be the same way as you're doing like at the start of third party libraries then your custom scripting

Comment: How does it matter? Angular injects the services/factories however it is placed or wherever it is.

Answer (score 0):

The order doesnt really matter in this case. Angularjs will automatically handle the dependencies between the dependencies.